# Show that $\limsup_{n \to \infty}a_n = \ell$ iff $\forall \varepsilon >0$ there are infinitely many indices $n$ for which $a_n > \ell - \varepsilon$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of real number. Show that $$\limsup_{n \to \infty}a_n = \ell$$ if and only if $\forall \varepsilon >0$ there are infinitely many indices $n$ for which $a_n > \ell - \varepsilon$ and only finitely many indices $n$ for which $a_n > \ell + \varepsilon.$

Noting that $\limsup_{n \to \infty}a_n =  \lim_{n \to \infty} \sup\{a_k \mid k \ge n \} =\ell $ and breaking down the limit definition I have that $\forall \varepsilon >0$ there exists $K \in \Bbb N$ such that for $n \ge K$ $$|\sup_{k \ge n} a_k- \ell |< \varepsilon \iff -\varepsilon < \sup_{k \ge n} a_k- \ell  <\varepsilon \iff  \ell-\varepsilon < \sup_{k \ge n} a_k  <\varepsilon +  \ell $$

So what I have is that for $k \ge n \ge K$  the following holds $\ell-\varepsilon < \sup_{k \ge n} a_k $. And similarly $k \ge n \ge K$ the inequality $\sup_{k \ge n} a_k  <\varepsilon +  \ell $ holds.

From what I understand the inequality $\ell-\varepsilon < \sup_{k \ge n} a_k  $ captures the statement

> there are infinitely many indices $n$ for which $a_n > \ell - \varepsilon$

but I don’t really see how $\sup_{k \ge n} a_k  <\varepsilon +  \ell  $ should capture the statement

> only finitely many indices $n$ for which $a_n > \ell + \varepsilon$

since from $\sup_{k \ge n} a_k  <\varepsilon +  \ell   $ it seems that there are none? Is it so that before $k \ge n$ this statement holds? If so why?

Comment: Yes, $k=1,2,...,n-1$ are the possibilities where $a_k \geq \epsilon +\ell$